# How do I use parameters to filter the XPath query result in BIRT

Tags: xml, eclipse, xpath, birt

I am trying to design **report in BIRT using xml data source** which is returned by a rest url. I want to design reports based on selected details.
So basically i want to apply filtering criteria. using below format to apply filter

Tool: Eclipse BIRT Report Designer XML Tab Editor. version: 4.6.0.v201606072122

**In Row mapping: 
/feed/entry/content/m:properties/[@d:id={?idparam?}]**

What is wrong in it.

It is throwing below exception.

```
Exception: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot execute the statement.
    org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: The filter definition is invalid. 

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.newException(ExceptionHandler.java:52)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:108)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ExceptionHandler.throwException(ExceptionHandler.java:84)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:586)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:980)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:607)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1251)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:233)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:178)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ExtractionResults.nextResultIterator(ExtractionResults.java:157)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:69)

at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:372)

at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)

Caused by: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: The filter definition is invalid. 

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.RelationInformation.getFilterValue(RelationInformation.java:240)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.RelationInformation.initialize(RelationInformation.java:130)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.RelationInformation.<init>(RelationInformation.java:58)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.impl.ResultSet.<init>(ResultSet.java:80)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.impl.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:137)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doExecuteQuery(OdaQuery.java:480)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.executeQuery(OdaQuery.java:444)

at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:575)

... 9 more
```

**XML :**

```
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:id>
    <d:external_id m:type="Edm.Int64">300000005060316</d:external_id>
    <d:salutation m:null="true" />
    <d:first_name>Shinichi(N)</d:first_name>
    <d:middle_name>E</d:middle_name>
    <d:last_name>Kudo</d:last_name>
    <d:person_number>12862</d:person_number>
    <d:work_email>shinichi@testmail.com</d:work_email>
    <d:work_phone_area_code>02</d:work_phone_area_code>
    <d:work_phone_country_code>63</d:work_phone_country_code>
    <d:work_phone_number>249-487-7110 x73977</d:work_phone_number>
    <d:work_phone_extension>111</d:work_phone_extension>
    <d:mobile_phone_country_code>02</d:mobile_phone_country_code>
    <d:mobile_phone_area_code>63</d:mobile_phone_area_code>
    <d:mobile_phone_number>(392)312-1107 x1599</d:mobile_phone_number>
    <d:date_of_birth m:type="Edm.DateTime">1998-12-10T00:00</d:date_of_birth>
    <d:legal_entity_id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:legal_entity_id>
    <d:hire_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-01T00:00</d:hire_date>
    <d:termination_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2019-12-12T00:00</d:termination_date>
    <d:gender>M</d:gender>
    <d:effective_start_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-01T00:00</d:effective_start_date>
    <d:username>RYAN.SITEAM@ORACLE.COM</d:username>
    <d:religion_id m:type="Edm.Int64">1</d:religion_id>
    <d:issue_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-09T00:00</d:issue_date>
    <d:passport_number>232123</d:passport_number>
    <d:passport_id m:type="Edm.Int64">64227</d:passport_id>
    <d:known_as>A</d:known_as>
    <d:passport_expiration_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-10-09T00:00</d:passport_expiration_date>
    <d:creation_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-01-30T10:11:08</d:creation_date>
    <d:last_update_date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-05T14:09:31</d:last_update_date>
    <d:address_id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:address_id>
    <d:mobile_phone_extension m:null="true" />
    <d:scheduler_op_code m:null="true" />
    <d:legacy_employee_identifier m:null="true" />
    <d:wtd_opt_in m:null="true" />
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml ?

Comment: I have added single entry of xml file.

Comment: what is xpath version?